# Jest/Jasmine .toContain() fails even though matching values are present

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jasmine, jestjs

I'm writing a simple React application with a `Button` component, which looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// shim to find stuff
Array.prototype.contains = function (needle) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
       if (this[i] == needle) return true;
   }
   return false;
};

class Button extends Component {
  propTypes: {
    text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    modifiers: React.PropTypes.array
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <span className={this.displayModifiers()}>{this.props.text}</span>
    );
  }
  displayModifiers() {
    const modifiers = this.props.modifiers || ["default"];
    if (modifiers.contains("default") ||
      modifiers.contains("danger")  ||
      modifiers.contains("success")) {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      // add default
      modifiers.push("defualt");
    }
    var classNames = "btn"
    for (var i = 0; i < modifiers.length; i++) {
      classNames += " btn-" + modifiers[i]
    }
    return(classNames);
  }
}

export default Button;
```

I then wrote this to test it:

```
it("contains the correct bootstrap classes", () => {
  expect(mount(<Button modifiers={["flat"]}/>).html()).toContain("<span class=\"btn btn-flat btn-default\"></span>");
});
```

That code should pass, but I receive the following error message:

```
expect(string).toContain(value)

Expected string:
  "<span class=\"btn btn-flat btn-defualt\"></span>"
To contain value:
  "<span class=\"btn btn-flat btn-default\"></span>"

  at Object.it (src\__tests__\Button.test.js:42:293)
```

Any ideas why this is not passing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> Use `.toContain` when you want to check that an item is in a list.

To test strings you should use `toBe` or `toEqual`

```
it("contains the correct bootstrap classes", () => {
  expect(mount(<Button modifiers={["flat"]}/>).html()).toBe("<span class=\"btn btn-flat btn-default\"></span>");
});
```

But there is a better way of testing the output rendered components: [snapshots](http://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/07/27/jest-14.html#why-snapshot-testing).

```
it("contains the correct bootstrap classes", () => {
  expect(mount(<Button modifiers={["flat"]}/>).html()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Note that you will need [enzymeToJson](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json) for snapshot testing using enzyme.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced `.toContain` with `.toEqual` but it still said the strings did not match. Snapshot testing works, but I prefer not to use it. Any ideas why `.toEqual` does not work when strings are the same?

Comment: Cause there is a typo in `defualt` ;)

Comment: Good catch! I guess I've been looking at this a little too long:)

Comment: Just compared it with tool, couldn't seen as well.

Comment: The docs also say:  `.toContain can also check whether a string is a substring of another string.`